# Flatten a related table into a multiple columns with SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to exact data from two tables in an IFS database (Oracle backend) using SQL. One table contains a list of Addresses, the other contains the Types those addresses have.

Example:

**Address** table:

```
Address1
Address2
```

**AddressType** table

```
Address1, DELIVERY, TRUE
Address1, DOCUMENT, FALSE
Address1, PAY, FALSE
Address2, DELIVERY, FALSE
Address2, PAY, TRUE
```

I can write a query that successfully gets the addresses, and their types, but I end up with a new row for every address type (essentially it just looks like the `AddressType` table).

```
SELECT 
    a.address_ID,
    at.address_type,
    at.address_type_default_b
FROM
    addresses a,
    address_type at
WHERE
    a.address_ID = at.address_ID
```

What I want is a query that will 'flatten' the table, move each type into a column. Based on the above example, the resulting table would have 2 rows, with 4 columns, see below.

**Desired result**

```
Address1, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
Address2, FALSE,*NULL*,TRUE
```

Note that I don't care what goes in for Null, blank, NA or NULL

Any help would be much appreciated. I realize I could do this in excel, but with the size of the data and the number of times I'll have to do this, it would be nice to do this in SQL.

Sorry about the poor formatting of the question... I can't figure out how to insert tables or get my sql to look correct.

Comment: You can try a pivot / crosstab command with syntax dependent on the engine.  If you have only 3 types you can join three times, one for each type.

Comment: Are you 'getting' data from oracle into MS Sql Server (using ssms or another tool) or is the code of PL SQL on oracle query engine?

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to what engine is being used. I do know that SQL Developer is used by the DBAs, does that help? I'm using the UI of the ERP software (IFS) to run my SQL queries, so I don't know what is going on in the back.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](http://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for that! I'll write better SQL now ;) In fact, this comment helped me troubleshoot my issue with the below solution, so its super helpful

Comment: @marc_s, when you have multiple Joins in a query, do the WHERE filter statements all come at the end, or in between the joins?

Comment: @Cameron: the **join** condition (what columns to compare to make the join) are part of the `INNER JOIN` or `OUTER JOIN` clauses. The `WHERE` clause only contains the "general purpose" conditions that apply to the whole result set. This also makes for a much cleaner code since it separates the join conditions from the actual `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only 3 statuses for an address and each status can happen only once:

In case you won't have any value, it will return null as desired

```
select a.address_ID,max( case when address_type='Delivery' then address_type_default_b end  ) 
,max( case when address_type='Document' then address_type_default_b end  )
,max( case when address_type='Pay' then address_type_default_b end  )
from address_table a
left join addresstype_table at on a.address_ID=b.address_ID
group by a.address_ID
```

Comment: Looks like that worked for me! Obviously my real life example is more complex, but I've only got 5 status's, but my group by has to be by two fields. However, I've test it and it's worked, so thanks for the answer!